# ExifInterface returns image orientation 0

Tags: android, image, attributes, exif

I am trying to get the orientation of an image (from gallery), but ExifInterface always returns 0.
here is the code:

int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 
                                       ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but I hope to help other developers struggling with this.

What helped me fix the issue was using:

```
android.support.media.ExifInterface
```

instead of

```
android.media.ExifInterface
```

It seems the `ExifInterface` from the support library does a better job at handling the various orientations. Please pay attention to the warnings the IDE gives. My warning was hiding inside a collapsed list of imports.